# http post headers

Tags: php, web-services, http-headers

When I post some headers in a request and view them on on the receiving page, most of them are prefixed with "HTTP_" except for a few like [CONTENT_TYPE] => text/xml [CONTENT_LENGTH] => 8647.

When I post my own headers (which are required for an external server) they then get prefixed e.g. My header: BATCH_TYPE   shows up as HTTP_BATCH_TYPE

I'm having some some problems with the headers i.e. I have to include ones like "BATCH_COUNT" & "VENDOR_ID" for an external server and when I test them internally I view them as HTTP_BATCH_COUNT and HTTP_VENDOR_ID

Is the "HTTP_" prefix normal or is there any way to remove it?

Thanks,

Comment: what technology are you using?

Comment: I'm using php and apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a CGI script to test, then it's the web server that's adding the HTTP_ prefix.  Don't worry - that prefix is almost certainly not present on the network.  You could use http://www.xhaus.com/headers to check.

Comment: Cheers didn;t know that site existed...it looks like they're all appearing ok. Prob must be something else....

Comment: The problem is with the headers are being received differently from what's being sent e.g.: VENDOR_ID is being received as Vendor-Id  BATCH-TYPE is being received as Batch-Type..\n Anyone know how to sort that? <br> <br> if you change the value of $url above to xhaus.com/headers yopu'll see what I mean.... – thegunner 1 min ago

Comment: @thegunner: xhaus.com/headers says "Header names have been capitalized, and may not appear exactly as transmitted by your browser. This should not make a difference to servers and clients, though, because the HTTP specification specifically states that HTTP headers should be case-insensitive".  You could use Wireshark to see what's actually being sent over the physical network.

Comment: Does that though not just refer to the capitalization of the letters and not the turning of underscore into hypen e.g. VENDOR_ID = Vendor-Id.
The people I'm posting to say thats why I'm getting the error message "incorrect Headers" and it's showing up in their error logs....annoying

Comment: I don't know.  Try Wireshark - it will tell you definitively what's going over the network.